# For loop doesn't properly filter

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I want to print two dataframes, where the first one is all the rows where column `a` is not NA and the second is all the rows where column `b` is not NA.

This is my code. It prints the whole dataframe both times, without triggering the filter.

```
a <- cbind(rep(NA, 100), seq(0,99)) 
b <- cbind(seq(0,99), rep(NA, 100))
df <- as.data.frame(rbind(a,b))
names(df) <- c("a", "b")


columns <- c("a", "b")

for (j in columns){
  df %>% filter(!is.na(j)) %>% print()
}
```

I also tried with `filter(j != "")` and received the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to why the downvote, I cannot know, but I can guess. You used functions that are not base R without issuing `library` calls for the packages that contain them, and you constructed  your example dataframe in a wasteful and possibly dangerous fashion using `cbind` unnecessarily and as.data.frame where a single `data.frame` call would have been more efficient, safer and more expressive.

```
cbind(as.Date("1970-01-01"))   # causes loss of attributes including class
#     [,1]
#[1,]    0
c(factor("a"))
#[1] 1
```

Here's how to properly construct an example like yours:

```
df <- data.frame( a = c(rep(NA, 100), seq(0,99)) , 
                   b = c(seq(0,99), rep(NA, 100)))
```

And you can get a column or object whose name you have in a character vector with `get` (assuming that there is an appropriate

```
columns <- c("a", "b")
library(dplyr)
for (j in columns){
    df %>% filter(!is.na( get(j) )) %>% print()
}
```

Comment: Curious, Mr. R guru, why is `cbind` of vectors casted to data frame *dangerous*?

Comment: Because it causes vectors to loose their attributes. If the arguments are not already dataframes then it makes a matrix. Likewise teh unnecessary use of `c` around vectors will cause them to loose attributes. We  see newbies putting `cbind` inside `data.fram`e (or in this case `as.data.frame`), but it often leads to obscure errors in code. In this case it was not the cause of the problem, but my guess was that the downvoter thought the code was a "bad" example for future users.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
not_na_a <- data.frame(which(!is.na(df$a)))

#> head(not_na_a)
  which..is.na.df.a..
1                 101
2                 102
3                 103
4                 104
5                 105
6                 106



not_na_b <- data.frame(which(!is.na(df$b)))

#> head(not_na_b)
  which..is.na.df.b..
1                   1
2                   2
3                   3
4                   4
5                   5
6                   6
```

Comment: Yes, except I'd like to do that in a for loop within a dplyr command.